# Connection Pool Object from Websphere Application Server

Tags: java, websphere, database-connection, connection-pooling

I am trying to connect to my data source using Connection pool objects in Websphere Application Server 8.5 and using Derby database. 
Here is the [TestCode](http://pastie.org/8533109) that I have written in my Enterprise Jave Project.
But I am getting the below mentioned exception:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'TESTCONN' does not exist
>       at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.BrokeredStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
>       at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcStatement.executeQuery(WSJdbcStatement.java:1017)
>       at dbConnect.TestClass.select(TestClass.java:43)
>       at dbConnect.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:19)

I have created a data source in Websphere application server and connection is working fine.

Connecting to data source using DriverManager works fine. However with Context (in the above shared code) connection is established but it says Schema does not exist. It seems jndi name is empty. Are there any settings in WAS or in Java Project that needs to be changed or added?

I am struggling with this problem since one week. Looking forward for help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to use the exact name of your schema while getting the connection.

Comment: Thankyou. I changed the query to "SELECT * FROM TESTCONN.TESTTABLE" but got the same error again. java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'TESTCONN' does not exist.

Comment: Can you provide the details (url) of the resource that you have configured?

Comment: This is the database url jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/testconn;user=testconn;password=testconn. Do you need any further information?

Comment: The main issue is that connection pool provides handle to a database which is different from the database in ij interactive tool. Is this due to the different port number (2809 instead of 1527) ? Am I missing something..

Answer (score 0):

Is there a schema with that name in your database? See http://db.apache.org/derby/faq.html#schema_exist

Comment: I checked the schema using the ij tool at the location C:/derby/bin/networkServer and it says that Schema is TestConn and table is TestTable. The main issue is that connection pool provides handle to a database which is different from the database shown through ij tool. Am I missing any configuration?

Comment: From the error message it still seems like you can connect to the database otherwise you wouldn't get that error. Is it possible that you have multiple instances of the database running on your machine?

Comment: Yes the code connects to database but the error comes at the select query and it says that schema does not exist. No there is only one instance of database running. When table is created for the above mentioned code, then I can access it. But the existing ones are not accessible. Looking forward for help. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the same user credentials for creating tables as you do when you are accessing them?

Comment: Yes Daniel, as you asked earlier, there were derby database instances running.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that a jar file (com.ibm.we.admin.client...) was missing.
Also there were two instances of derby databases were running. 
Thank you!